# Ada generic package usage and compliation error "non-visible declaration"

Tags: generics, ada

I am new to Ada and I'm trying to make a generic quicksort package that can take an integer array of n numbers. The integers in the array must within 1 to 1000.

When I compile the following code, it told me

```
main.adb:: "Quicksort" is not visible
main.adb:: non-visible declaration at quick_sort.ads:6
main.adb:: "sort" is undefined
```

However, I cannot find the reason why it is like so and it just seems to be the same feeling that I can find on generic tutorial. I really appreciate that if someone can help me clear my mind why this is happening and how I can use generic correctly.

I wrote the following generic package declaration and body.

**quick_sort.ads file**

```
package quick_sort is
generic
    type element_type is private;
    type array_type is array(Natural range <>) of element_type;

    procedure Quicksort(arr: in out array_type);
end quick_sort;
```

**quick_sort.adb file**(snippet)

```
package body quick_sort is
    procedure Quicksort(arr: in out array_type) is
        left: integer := arr'First;
        right: integer := arr'Last;

        procedure partition is
        ....
        begin
            pivot := find_pivot(arr(left), arr((left+right)/2), arr(right));
            -- do the partition for the array
            while left <= right loop
                while arr(left) < pivot loop
                    left := left + 1;
                end loop;
                while arr(right) > pivot loop
                    right := right - 1;
                end loop;
                if left <= right then
                    swap(arr(left), arr(right));
                    left := left + 1;
                    right := right - 1;
                end if;
             end loop;
        end partition;
    begin
        if arr'Length > 1 then
            partition;
            Quicksort(arr(arr'First..right));
            Quicksort(arr(left..arr'Last));
         end if;
    end Quicksort;
end quick_sort;
```

**main.adb**

```
with quick_sort;
procedure main is

    subtype item is integer range 1..1000;
    arr: array(1..3) of item;
    input: item;
    package sort is new Quicksort(element_type => item);
begin
    for i in 1..3 loop
        get(input);
        arr(i) := input;
    end loop;
    sort(arr);
end main;
```

Edit:

I tried with/without the "use quick_sort" clause.
Either way, the compiler will give me the following 2 errors

```
a generic package is not allowed in a use clause
"Quicksort" is not the name of a generic package
```

I cannot figure out if I used some wrong declarator. Any thought on it? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Could you try to indent the source text properly?  It might make it easier for everybody to read and understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The line numbers in the error message you quote do not match with the source files you include in your question.  It might be useful to fix that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Main` begins `with Quick_Sort;`. This means that `Main`’s code has direct access to `Quick_Sort` but not to its contents - you have to qualify them by saying `Quick_Sort.<whatever>`.

You can either begin `Main` with

```
with Quick_Sort; use Quick_Sort;
```

or instantiate the generic with

```
package sort is new Quick_Sort.Quicksort(element_type => item);
```

That resolves the `"Quicksort" is not visible` problem. However as you report, the compiler now says `"Quicksort" is not the name of a generic package`; which is true, because it’s the name of a generic *procedure*.

Of course that last line above should read

```
procedure sort is new Quick_Sort.Quicksort(element_type => item);
```

which leads to the new error

```
missing actual "Array_Type"
in instantiation of "Quicksort" declared at yeelan.ada:6
instantiation abandoned
```

which means that instead of

```
arr: array(1..3) of item;
```

you need to write something like

```
type Item_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Item;
Arr : Item_Array (1 .. 3);
```

and then

```
procedure Sort is new Quicksort(Element_Type => Item,
                                Array_Type => Item_Array);
```

You’ll then get an error about Get being undefined, but the reason for that would be the answer to another question.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thank you for answering. I tried use quick_sort and the compiler told me that "a generic package is not allowed in a use clause". If I remove the use clause and use the way you pointed out, which I believe it should work, it tolds me "Quicksort" is not the name of a generic package". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @yeelan: In the code you posted, `quick_sort` is a package, not a generic package, and `quick_sort.Quicksort` is a generic procedure. If `use quick_sort` gave you that error, then you've modified your code so that `quick_sort` *is* a generic package. You can make either the package or the procedure generic; once you decide that, you need to be consistent in how you use it. Using such similar names for the package and the procedure is confusing. Since the procedure is the only thing in the package, you might put the (generic) procedure at the top level and not use a package at all.